# Why is my change calculator not working for coins?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to make a program that calculates tax and what change needs to be given back, but for some reason, it doesn't tell me what coins to give back. The code tells me which bills I would need to give back, but the coins that are in the decimals don't work. I've tried looking all over stack exchange for a solution, but if I'm being honest, I'm not really sure  what to even look for in the first place, so I haven't found a solution. I'm also new to Java and text-based coding in general, so any feedback is appreciated!
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Decisions1 {
    static String taskValue = "C1";
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initiates the scanner
        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        //creates the variables for the total
        double total1 = 0;
        //asks for the total cost of all goods
        System.out.println("Please enter the total cost of all goods. This program will add tax and calculate the change you must give back to the customer.");
        total1 = myInput.nextDouble();
        //performs calculations for tax
        double tax2 = (total1*1.13);
        double tax1 = (double) Math.round(tax2 * 100) / 100;
        //creates variable for amount paid
        double paid1 = 0;
        //prints info to the user and asks how much cash they received
        System.out.println("You entered $" + total1 + "\n" + "Total with tax = $" + tax1 + "\n" + "Please enter how much cash was paid by the customer. The amount of change owed to the customer will be displayed.");
        paid1 = myInput.nextDouble();
        //checks if customer has paid enough
        if (tax1 > paid1) {
            double owed1 = (tax1-paid1);
            System.out.println("The customer still owes $" + owed1 + "!");
        } else if (tax1 == paid1) { //checks if the customer has given exact change
            System.out.println("The customer has paid the exact amount. You don't have to give them any change.");
        } else if (tax1 < paid1) {
            //starts change calculations
            //variables for money units
            double oneHundred = 100;
            double fifty = 50;
            double twenty = 20;
            double ten = 10;
            double five = 5;
            double toonie = 2;
            double loonie = 1;
            double quarter = 0.25;
            double dime = 0.10;
            double nickel = 0.05;
            double penny = 0.01;
            //variable for change owed (rounded to 2 decimal places
            double change1 = Math.round((paid1-tax1)*100)/100;
            //calculates remainder
            double oneHundredMod = (change1 % oneHundred);
            //divides and removes decimal places
            double oneHundredOwed = (change1 / oneHundred);
            String oneHundredOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) oneHundredOwed);
            //does the same thing for fifty
            double fiftyMod = (oneHundredMod % fifty);
            double fiftyOwed = (oneHundredMod / fifty);
            String fiftyOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) fiftyOwed);
            //twenties
            double twentyMod = (fiftyMod % twenty);
            double twentyOwed = (fiftyMod / twenty);
            String twentyOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) twentyOwed);
            //tens
            double tenMod = (twentyMod % ten);
            double tenOwed = (twentyMod / ten);
            String tenOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) tenOwed);
            //fives
            double fiveMod = (tenMod % five);
            double fiveOwed = (tenMod / five);
            String fiveOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) fiveOwed);
            //toonies
            double tooniesMod = (fiveMod % toonie);
            double tooniesOwed = (fiveMod / toonie);
            String tooniesOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) tooniesOwed);
            //loonies
            double looniesMod = (tooniesMod % loonie);
            double looniesOwed = (tooniesMod / loonie);
            String looniesOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) looniesOwed);
            //quarters
            double quartersMod = (looniesMod % quarter);
            double quartersOwed = (looniesMod / quarter);
            String quartersOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) quartersOwed);
            //dimes
            double dimesMod = (quartersMod % dime);
            double dimesOwed = (quartersMod / dime);
            String dimesOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) dimesOwed);
            //nickels
            double nickelsMod = (dimesMod % nickel);
            double nickelsOwed = (dimesMod / nickel);
            String nickelsOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) nickelsOwed);
            //and finally, pennies!
            double penniesMod = (nickelsMod % penny);
            double penniesOwed = (nickelsMod / penny);
            String penniesOwed1 = String.valueOf((int) penniesOwed);
            System.out.println("TOTAL CHANGE:" + "\n" + "\n" + "$100 Bill(s) = " + oneHundredOwed1 + "\n" + "$50 Bill(s) = " + fiftyOwed1 + "\n" + "$20 Bill(s) = " + twentyOwed1 + "\n" + "$10 Bill(s) = " + tenOwed1 + "\n" + "$5 Bill(s) = " + fiveOwed1 + "\n" + "Toonie(s) = " + tooniesOwed1 + "\n" +"Loonie(s) = " + looniesOwed1 + "\n" + "Quarter(s) = " + quartersOwed1 + "\n" + "Dime(s) = " + dimesOwed1 + "\n" + "Nickel(s) = " + nickelsOwed1 + "\n" + "Pennies = " + penniesOwed1);
        }
    }//end main
}// end Decisions1
```

Comment: did you try debugging your code?

Comment: I looked through it, and it doesn't say there are any bugs.

Comment: you should calculate everything in pennys and not pounds or dollars or whatever, this is because the type `double` is not suited to proper deal with decimal values like `0.1`

Comment: Oh, okay, I will try that! Thank you for telling me that!

Comment: I think the problem here stamps of the use of `%` on value lower than 1, which might not be well defined in java.

Comment: I'm going to multiply coin values by 100 to show them in cents, and when I display them to the user, I will divide them by 100.